# A yacc reduce/reduce conflict I can't explain

Tags: yacc, context-free-grammar

I'm getting a shift/reduce and reduce/reduce conflict that I believe shouldn't happen.  Obviously I'm doing something wrong, so someone explain to me what I'm missing.

My stripped down grammar:

```
/*
 * Test SQL Grammar
 */

%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
%}

            /* Yacc's YYSTYPE UNION */
%union {
            char* str;   /* Pointer to constant string (malloc'd in lex) */
       }

%token SELECT FROM AS ROWID ROWNUM NEXTVAL CURRVAL NULL
%token <str> IDENTIFIER STRING NUMBER

%%

query_block
            : SELECT 
              select_list
              FROM row_source_list
            ;

select_list
            : '*'
            | select_item_list 
            ;

select_item_list
            : select_item_list ',' select_item
            | select_item
            ;

select_item
            : row_source '.' '*'
            | expr
            | expr IDENTIFIER
            ;

row_source_list
            : row_source_list ',' row_source
            | row_source
            ;

row_source
            : IDENTIFIER
            | IDENTIFIER '.' IDENTIFIER 
            | IDENTIFIER opt_AS IDENTIFIER
            | IDENTIFIER '.' IDENTIFIER opt_AS IDENTIFIER
            ;

opt_AS
            : /* Empty */
            | AS
            ;

expr
            : IDENTIFIER '.' IDENTIFIER
            | IDENTIFIER '.' ROWID
            | IDENTIFIER '.' IDENTIFIER '.' IDENTIFIER
            | IDENTIFIER '.' IDENTIFIER '.' ROWID
            | ROWNUM 
            | ROWID 
            | STRING 
            | NUMBER
            | IDENTIFIER '.' CURRVAL
            | IDENTIFIER '.' NEXTVAL
            | NULL
            ;
```

The conflicts seem to arrise because yacc doesn't know if it is working on the select_list (expr list) or the row_source_list.  State 26 of y.output details the conflict:

```
state 26

12 row_source: IDENTIFIER '.' IDENTIFIER .
14           | IDENTIFIER '.' IDENTIFIER . opt_AS IDENTIFIER
17 expr: IDENTIFIER '.' IDENTIFIER .
19     | IDENTIFIER '.' IDENTIFIER . '.' IDENTIFIER
20     | IDENTIFIER '.' IDENTIFIER . '.' ROWID

 AS   shift, and go to state 16
 '.'  shift, and go to state 33

 IDENTIFIER  reduce using rule 15 (opt_AS)
 IDENTIFIER  [reduce using rule 17 (expr)]
 '.'         [reduce using rule 12 (row_source)]
 $default    reduce using rule 17 (expr)

 opt_AS  go to state 34
```

Now the basic rule for "query_block" states that a row_source_list must be preceded by the "FROM" keyword, so I don't see why yacc is combining the two into one state.

```
query_block
            : SELECT 
              select_list
              FROM row_source_list
            ;
```

I've traced the states and it ends up in this state before finding the "FROM" keyword.
I don't understand why it is considering the row_source_list before it recognized "FROM".

Answer (score 0):

(I flagged this as "no longer reproducible fault" as the OP had solved it trivially, but the flag was aged/timed out).

[As it has an answer I'll transcribe the answer so at least the question is noted as answered.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que)

As the OP states:

> I found it right after posting. It's the first line in the select_item rule. I should have caught that earlier.

Which to clarify, the `select_item` rule should be:

```
select_item
            : expr
            | expr IDENTIFIER
            ;
```

Which removes the ambiguity.